# Use case for iBeacon - Send HTTP request with phone's IDFA

Tags: android, ios, ibeacon, android-ibeacon

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

A user walks into a store with a beacon placed. When the user/phone is within X feet of the beacon, the beacon (or maybe the phone?) fires an HTTP request to a server sending the IDFA of the phone to the server (i.e. sends a request to http://myserver.com?idfa=1234324234234234 ).

Is this possible using beacons?

Comment: I you need anything else, just ask. i´ve been working with beacons recently.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,It´s possible.

You can implement it on the phone side with a library called [AltBeacon](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library), here you have the specs [site](http://altbeacon.org/)

You just need to implement the beacon ranging function to your `Activity` and then send an http call to your server with the info taken from the found/nearby beacon.

Here you have a working example from the same AltBeacon repository.

https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/altbeacon/beaconreference/RangingActivity.java

This is just a except so you can see how easy it is to range beacons.

```
@Override
    public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
        beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
           @Override
           public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
              if (beacons.size() > 0) {
                 //EditText editText = (EditText)RangingActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.rangingText);
                 Beacon firstBeacon = beacons.iterator().next();
                 logToDisplay("The first beacon " + firstBeacon.toString() + " is about " + firstBeacon.getDistance() + " meters away.");
              }
           }

        });

        try {
            beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myRangingUniqueId", null, null, null));
        } catch (RemoteException e) {   }
    }
```